# Is it possible to arrange jsfiddle codes into separate folders

Tags: directory, jsfiddle

I have created a lot of code snippets on jsfiddle.net. I am seeing them all in my dashboard page at jsfiddle and just looking for a way to create some folders there and arrange my codes into different and more meaningful folders.

URL is - [www.jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at the moment - really sorry.

Comment: completely agree with you @zalun, I too searched the documentation a lot but couldn't find. Hope jsfiddle soon adds this missing feature to their site. Thanks for confirming.